# How do I hide single category post on my post page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, pages

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'numberposts' => 6,
    'offset' => 0
) ); ?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 com-xs-12 pannel">
            <div class="pannel-news">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="sidebar-color">
                    <strong>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `category__not_in`

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'numberposts' => 6,
    'offset' => 0,
    "category__not_in" => 148,
) );
```

you will see more options here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. This is the correct answer